# How to add caption

Tags: beamer, captions

I have added a figure using the following commands in my beamer presentation.

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Abstract}
    \begin{columns}[c]
        \begin{column}{.7\textwidth}
         The point evaluation of an affine function on a compact convex subset of a locally convex topological vector space 
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.3\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=.5\textheight]{ABC.jpg}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

Now the environment not accepting the command `\caption{}` immediately after `\includegraphics{}`. Please suggest how to add a caption below the figure.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you by providing a minimal compilable code example. Just a hint: The `figure` environment does also work in beamer but without floating so it is safe to use it to get a caption.

Comment: unrelated to your problem: don't specify both the height and width of an image, this will most likely distort the image.

Comment: I would follow the advice of @TeXnician and use a `figure` environment. If this is for some reason not possible, you could have a look at the `\captionof` macro from the `caption` package.

Comment: Also unrelated to your problem: the two columns of .3 and .7 \textwidth are too wide for your frame (there is a small separation between them) Either make them a bit smaller or use `\begin{columns}[c,onlytextwidth]`

Comment: @TeXnician Would you like to write an answer?

Comment: @TeXnician Thanks! One question less in the list of answered :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in other document classes you have to use either a figure environment (which does not float in beamer) or something like `\captionof`. The latter would be a command from the `caption` package which used to have unintended side effects in beamer (although they should be resolved by now as noted by [@samcarter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/36296/samcarter) in a comment).

Following the simple route:

```
\begin{column}{.3\textwidth}
  \begin{figure}
    \caption{Test}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=.5\textheight]{ABC.jpg}
  \end{figure}
\end{column}
```

Comment: My impression is that Axel Sommerfeldt fixed most problems between caption and beamer and at the moment there are no big problems between them.

Comment: @samcarter Oh, I haven't done that many beamer presentations lately. Good to know, thanks.